# MySQL TIMESTAMP not updating when inserting through PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a column in MySQL though PHPMyAdmin that looks like this

[image: PHPMyAdmin shot]

When I insert through PHPMyAdmin into the table and not put anything in the time column it works and puts the time in, however when I do it through PHP with the following script

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `products` 

     VALUES ('', '$title', '', '$photo', '$price', '$details', '$description_short', '$description', '$dimensions', '$colour', '$scatid', '$type', '$brand', 'Y', '$size')") ;
```

(the third '' is the time column) it seems to put the timestamp as 0000-00-00 00:00:00

I have had a look around and seem to be doing everything right from looking through some other Stack Overflow posts.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Better use `DATETIME`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have 2 options:

option 1:

explicitly use "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" (or "NOW()" as others have said), like this:

```
"INSERT INTO `products` VALUES ('', '$title', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', '$photo', '$price', '$details', '$description_short', '$description', '$dimensions', '$colour', '$scatid', '$type', '$brand', 'Y', '$size')"
```

option 2:

implicitly use the default value. To use this, you need to specify the columns you're inserting (between the table name "products" and the keyword VALUES), skipping the timestamp column both in the column list and values list.

I personally prefer option 2 for debug purposes (you can instantly see which columns are for which values and viceversa without looking at the db schema)

Answer (score 2):

Because you have putted it as blank `''`

If you want it to be current timestamp then the query should be

```
INSERT INTO products(list of column_name except time column_name) values (values of list of columns present in column list)
```

You can also use `NOW()` for inserting date and time in database

Comment: Agreed. Explicitly listing the column names is [good practice](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jamesw/archive/2011/10/03/a-list-of-sql-best-practices.aspx) - one of the problems it helps you avoid is your current one, where you are not letting the RDBMS insert the current timestamp automatically.

Answer (score 2):

May be don't use '' may be a problem use

```
NOW()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting a blank (0) value inside the timestamp column.

You can:

1 - modify your query to exclude the timestamp column:

insert into (foo, bar) values ("val1", "val2")

2 - replace "" with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP at the third position inside values

Comment: Despite "pippo" and "pluto" are the universal generic variables used in Italy when teaching programming, you should use "foo", "bar" and "baz" when writing english ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the default value to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of putting that in the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Use NOW() mysql command as value for timestamp column

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `products` VALUES ('', '$title', NOW(), '$photo', '$price', '$details', '$description_short', '$description', '$dimensions', '$colour', '$scatid', '$type', '$brand', 'Y', '$size')") ;
```